# How to find misspellings in data

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to find the misspellings in TOWN_C field. Data looks something like below. There is no specific pattern, sometimes misspelling can be at the beginning, sometimes it can be in middle or at the end. Length of misspelling can be different too.
I am using SQL Server Management Studio to execute the queries. I used `SUBSTR` to find out duplicates along with the `left outer join`. But that does not give only misspelling. I still need to go and manually look at data.

Data ->

```
Achampet
ACHEMPET
AGIA
AGIYA
ASHOK NAGAR
ASHOKNAGAR
ASHOKNAGER
```

SQL query which I am using ->

```
Select distinct(T3.TOWN__C)
 From (Select T1.Sub_Str, Count(T1.Sub_Str) as Y
       From (SELECT TOWN__C, SUBSTRING(TOWN__C, 1, 3) as Sub_Str
             FROM [SALESFORCE].[dbo].[Outlet Master] group by TOWN__C)T1
       Group by T1.Sub_Str having count(*)> 1)T2
 Left outer join
     [SALESFORCE].[dbo].[Outlet Master]T3
 On T2.Sub_Str = SUBSTRING(T3.TOWN__C, 1, 3)
 Order by T3.TOWN__C
```

Is there a way to find out all such cases using SQL or Excel or anything else?

Comment: Assuming you know all the values your end user _should_ be using then you can use data validation.

Comment: very true. But unfortunately, they don't know the correct/final value for these towns. So its on me to provide them this misspelling list and then they will analyze which one is correct :(

Comment: So, to put this in more concrete terms (since you don't really *define* misspelling in your question), are you looking for a query which will identify entries which are *similar* but for which multiple distinct spellings are provided? If so, what similarity metric are we to use? Something like soundex? Or edit distances?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `SOUNDEX`, to try to locate values where multiple spellings have been used for "similar" names:

```
declare @t table (town varchar(35) not null)
insert into @t(town) values
('Achampet'),
('ACHEMPET'),
('AGIA'),
('AGIYA'),
('ASHOK NAGAR'),
('ASHOKNAGAR'),
('ASHOKNAGER'),
('Downtown'),
('DOWNTOWN'),
('DownTown')

select
    v.*
from
    (select
        *,
        MIN(town) OVER (PARTITION BY town_sound) as minTown,
        MAX(town) OVER (PARTITION BY town_sound) as maxTown
    from
        @t
            cross apply
        (select SOUNDEX(REPLACE(town,' ','')) as town_sound) u
    ) v
where minTown != maxTown
```

Note that this doesn't return "downtown" where the only variations are in capitalization, but does return all of the values in your given sample data, which I assume were all meant to be found as possible misspellings.

Also note that [`SOUNDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql) has had a chequered history and under older versions of SQL Server it was usually recommended that a "better" soundex be implemented as a UDF. You should be able to find versions of that with a simple search, if required.

Note, also, that [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) was specifically designed around English pronunciation. Again, you may be able to find a better tailored function as a UDF for specific other languages.

Results:

```
town          town_sound minTown       maxTown
------------- ---------- ------------- ------------
AGIA          A200       AGIA          AGIYA
AGIYA         A200       AGIA          AGIYA
ASHOK NAGAR   A225       ASHOK NAGAR   ASHOKNAGER
ASHOKNAGAR    A225       ASHOK NAGAR   ASHOKNAGER
ASHOKNAGER    A225       ASHOK NAGAR   ASHOKNAGER
Achampet      A251       Achampet      ACHEMPET
ACHEMPET      A251       Achampet      ACHEMPET
```